# Access geometry.coordinates of sliced vector grid

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-grid, vector-layer

I am trying to represent LineString GeoJSON as vector tile layer using Leaflet.VectorGrid.

But i need to do some interactive by clicking on vector tile layer.
but this vector tile layer has came with only properties, and did't came with geometry. So that i need to access coordinates to show elevation profile on chart.

```
var tileLayer = L.vectorGrid.slicer(geojson, {
      rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
      vectorTileLayerStyles: {
        sliced: {
          color: "red",
          weight: 3,
         opacity: 0
                    }
      },
      maxZoom: 22,
  indexMaxZoom: 5,       // max zoom in the initial tile index
      interactive: true,
      getFeatureId: function(feature) {
          return feature.properties["id"]
      }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layer event handler to process mouse `click` event, see sliced GeoJSON example http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/demo-geojson.html (example does not work in IE11).

Example below catches mouse `click` event for `L.vectorGrid.slicer` layer, changes feature line color from black to red and displays popup with feature id at click position.

**EDIT**: Since GeoJSON vector layer is sliced, GeoJSON geometry is not part of vector layer. To access it in click event, we have to search for it in original GeoJSON object.

```
function getGeometry(geoJSON, idProperty) {
  var retVal = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < geoJSON.features.length; i++) {
    if (geoJSON.features[i].properties.id == idProperty) {
      retVal = geoJSON.features[i].geometry;
      break;
    }
  };
  return retVal ; 
};

var tileLayer = L.vectorGrid.slicer(geojson, {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: {
      stroke: true,
      color: 'black',
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1
    }
  },
  maxZoom: 22,
  indexMaxZoom: 5,
  interactive: true,
  getFeatureId: function(feature) {
      return feature.properties['id']
  }
})
.on('click', function(e) {
  var properties = e.layer.properties;
  var geometry = getGeometry(geojson, properties.id);
  L.popup()
    .setContent(properties['id'])
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map);
  var style = {
    stroke: true,
    color: 'red',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1
  };
  vectorGrid.setFeatureStyle(properties['id'], style);
})
.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I know, and i have done this already, but i need to access geometry.coordinates of sliced GeoJSON.

Comment: @EslamFarag I updated my answer with `getGeometry` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It works.